# Access attribute from another class in the same module?

Tags: python

Let's say I have person.py and it looks something like this:

```
class Eyes:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color

class Head:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.have_dark_eyes = ???
        self.size = size
```

Then:

```
import person

eyes = person.Eyes("blue")
head = person.Head("small")
if (head.has_dark_eyes == True):
    ...
```

I would like to use the attribute `color` to set have_dark_eyes to `True` or `False`, but how? I was thinking of replacing `???` with `True if color == "brown" else False` but it won't work.

Thanks.

Comment: you'd need to pass in an instance of class `Eyes`

Comment: Please review your educational materials on classes, attributes, instances, and variable scoping.  Your problem is that `color` has no meaning to `Head`.  I suspect that you actually want an instance of `Eyes` to be an attribute of a `Head` instance.  In that case, `head.eyes.color` would be readily available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to, at the very least, provide `Head` with an instance of `Eyes`, e.g. something like

```py
class Eyes:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color

class Head:
    def __init__(self, eyes, size):
        self.have_dark_eyes = eyes.color == 'brown'
        self.size = size
```

Example usage:

```py
dark_eyes = Eyes('brown')
head = Head(dark_eyes, 10)
print(head.have_dark_eyes)  # Prints True
```

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was looking for! Would you say it's common practice or there would be a better way to do it? Thanks

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary here. Maybe one thing to be aware of is that whenever you find yourself using `True`/`False` as part of boolean expressions (such as your `if (head.has_dark_eyes == True)`), that can typically be simplified away (in your case into `if (head.has_dark_eyes)`).